# Which tool can list writing access to a specific variable in C?

Tags: c++, c, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

Unfortunately I'm not even sure how this sort of static analysis is called. It's not really control flow analysis because I'm not looking for function calls and I don't really need data flow analysis because I don't care about the actual values.

I just need a tool that lists the locations (file, function) where writing access to a specific variable takes place. I don't even care if that list contained lines that are unreachable. I could imagine that writing a simple parser could suffice for this task but I'm certain that there must be a tool out there that does this simple analysis.

As a poor student I would appreciate free or better yet open source tools and if someone could tell me how this type of static analysis is actually called, I would be equally grateful!

EDIT: I forgot to mention there's no pointer arithmetic in the code base.

Comment: At runtime you can debug and place a memory breakpoint at your variable address, but I know that's not what you're asking.

Comment: Can't you just ask the compiler to produce an AST?

Comment: I would still need to walk and analyze the AST. Since this is just a small task I'm still somewhat reluctant to invest a few hours of coding and testing into something like this. I can't be the first one who wants to know whether a variable is written to in a certain file and in that file only.

Comment: @Lichtblitz If you think that statically predicting what a program does at run-time is just a small task that would take you a few hours (that you might as well spend on something else), you may be  underestimating the difficulty of the problem. A reasonably precise static analyzer for a reasonably large subset of C should not take less than ten man-years. It will take you more than a few hours to find the ten man-years analyzer that already does exactly what you wish and to make it output its results in the format you want. Unless you are thinking of a syntactic solution based on regexps

Comment: @PascalCuoq I'm just looking for a tiny fraction of the subset of a single feature of that ten man-years analyzer. If you had read my text you'd know that I don't care about values, not even about reachability. I just want to get all occurrences where the value of a specific variable is written. I just want to find out all places where a specific variable happens to be on the left hand side of an assignment for example.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you make the variable `const` and then note down all the errors where your compiler bans write access?

**Note**: This won't catch errors where the memory underlying the variable is written to in some erroneous manner such as a buffer overrun.

**EDIT**: For example:

```
const int a = 1;
a = 2;
a = 3;
```

My compiler produces:

```
1>MyProg.c(46): error C3892: 'a' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
1>MyProg.c(47): error C3892: 'a' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

Comment: Heh, that sounds like a nice work-around. I would still need to automate the process to stay sane if I wanted to perform this test for a number of variables but it sounds more reliable than a home-brewed parser.

Comment: @Lichtblitz Are you trying to put together some kind of report on written to variables?  I'm curious to know why you need to automate it?

Comment: If you mean compilation warnings, the compiler will not list all writes to a `const` variable in this fashion, and if you mean run-time errors from executing the program, the problem is that the program stops at the first write.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Writing to a const variable is an error unless you cast away the const.  Clearly it would be possible to enumerate such errors...  See my edit:

Comment: Yes, the compiler emits two warnings for the simplistic example you show, but it emits only one for http://ideone.com/pMu4sy . The compiler does not show all the writes to `a` and you cannot even easily infer the first write, not to mention the three of them, from the “discards qualifiers from pointer target type” warning you **do** get. You can get the first write from executing the program (but not the latter ones) though. This said, if the OP's program looks like your example, then yes, he can make do with compiler warnings.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Interesting, that example doesn't compile in my compiler (VC2010) and does enumerate the attempts to write to `a`.  It doesn't flag the attempts to write to `x` but then `x` can't point to `a` without a const cast so I'd expect that to be the case.

Comment: Just to be very clear, the `x = &a;` in my program only causes a warning because of the `const` your method adds to the declaration of `a`. The real program declared `int a = 1;` and it was a valid program, in which I was hoping to detect all writes to `a`. So the compiler warning on `x = &a;` helps me in my endeavor, but what I would have really liked to see was line `*(int *)x = 3;` (valid in the original program). On the other hand, the OP has stated that he does not have pointer arithmetic in his program, whatever that means, so the compiler warning route may work for him.

Comment: “that example doesn't compile in my compiler” Were you trying to compile it as a C++ program? My program is invalid as a C++ program, although I believe that an explicit cast to `(void*)` makes it acceptable.

Comment: I'm starting to understand that I severely underestimated the complexity of the task. With "no pointer arithmetic" I was trying to say that all variables are directly referenced by name rather than by incrementing pointers and such which would add a whole new layer of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

This works for C programs that you have made the effort to analyze with [Frama-C's value analysis](http://frama-c.com/try_out.html). It is Open Source and the dependency information is also available programmatically. As static analyzers go, it is rather on the “precise” side of the spectrum. It will work better if your target is embedded C code.

Comment: Does it also tell me _where_ writing access takes place (file/function)? The possible values are nice to know but not my main concern for this task.

Comment: In this screenshot, it shows that the variable `S` the user is interested is in last written at the statement `S += i;`. The values are shown because they are computed too (they are necessary to answer the question in presence of arrays, arrays of pointers, ...) but what is displayed here (in yellow) is the writes that define the value of `S`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq will it also catch writes through pointers, i.e.`int foo(int *)` called as `foo(S)`?

Comment: @peterph Yes. This is why the values (of integer variables and of pointers) are computed. In technical terms, it is a context-sensitive path-sensitive static analysis.

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try, then. Thanks for the recommendation :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure such a tool could be written. Pointers can be used to change arbitary data in memory without having any reference to other variables pointing to that data. Think about functions like `memset()`, which change whole blocks of memory.

If you are not interested in these kind of mutations, you would still have to take transitive pointers into account. In C, you can have any number of pointers pointing to the same data, and you would have to analyze where copies of these pointers are made. And then these copies can be copied again, ...

So even in the "simple" case it would require quite a big amount of code analysis.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that there is no pointer arithmetic in the code base.

Comment: That eases things, but doesn't make them trivial. But the hints provided by @Benji and Antoine seem like a very good workaround to me.

Comment: If the pointer was initialized at the variable address, it could be shown (lots of false positive though). Otherwise, writing at arbitrary addresses will not be caught but that's a corner case.

Comment: @Antoine Depends on how accurate it should be. In some scenarios where the writes would depend on input it would get extremely tough, but you could be able to get answer in the form of "IF (Min < var1 < Max) THEN no access to var2". For dynamically allocated memory it is actually a no-go (imho).

Comment: @peterph you're right, for non trivial cases it would be very hard to write an accurate tool. llvm's [safe code](http://safecode.cs.illinois.edu/index.html) uses a mixture of static and dynamic analysis - although not exactly for the same problem.